# How to develop a doodle pad?

Tags: flash

How can I make a doodle pad like [this](http://www.itasveer.com/doodlepad.do#) for a website? Is flash the only option? I wanted to make one for advert design.

**Edit**

Basically, I want to provide features like customized text (font/color/size) and placement, option to put any image with scale/rotate/transform option etc so that he can design advert himself.

**Edit2**

What could be alternative approaches to design this kind of editor?

**Edit3**

I've also seen options like [o3d](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O3D) and [webGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) but it seems they won't work on most of the browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash is not the only option. You can write a [Java applet](http://java.sun.com/applets/) to do this, or use the new [HTML 5 Canvas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element) with javascript.

Your question is a bit broad - you need to provide more detail for more specific answers.

Comment: @Oded: I've made an edit in question with more specifications.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question depends a lot on your target audience. Flash has a broad installation base (but probably won't ever work on iOS devices). Since it's a plugin, it'll work the same across all browsers that support it, including dinosaurs like IE6.  HTML5/Canvas, will work on most modern browsers, including iOS devices, but will fail to function on older browsers, and most versions of IE.

Beyond that, I believe this is a bit of a broad question for S.O. Pick up a book on your language of choice and start coding; when you hit things you can't solve by reading the documentation, ask specific questions.